# Odds of Specific Numbers Being Drawn Last From 1 to 50

Tags: probability

I'm trying to work out the odds of something happening in a mobile Gacha game, Mario Kart Tour.

Basically there's a random element to the game where you effectively draw items from a hat. The contents of the hat are random except for 3 items that are guaranteed to be in the hat. I wanted to work out the odds that the last two items were two of these guaranteed items.

So I figured it's like having 50 numbers in a hat, what are the odds that you'll draw 1 & 2 out last, order doesn't matter.

Comment: The odds of drawing them last is the same as the odds of drawing them first.

Comment: So is that (3 in 50) x (2 in 50) = 0.0024? It doesn't feel so simple?

Comment: Why 3 and 2?  It should be 2 in 50 and 1 in 49.

Comment: If you want the odds that the last two are among $1, 2, 3$ then you want ($3$ in $50$) x ($2$ in $49$) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's list all the items in the order you draw them from the hat. There are $50$ places in the list, and the $3$ guaranteed items occupy $3$ of those places. The number of ways to choose these $3$ places with no restrictions is $\binom{50}{3}$. The number of ways to choose these $3$ places with the restriction that they must include the last two is $48$: you simply choose one of the first $48$ places, plus the last two. So the probability that the last two are among the chosen places is $\frac{48}{\binom{50}{3}}$.

Alternatively, use Ned's method (from the comments): the probability that the last item is among the $3$ guaranteed is $\frac{3}{50}$, the probability (contingent on that event) that the second-to-last is one of the remaining $2$ guaranteed is $\frac{2}{49}$, so the probability is $\frac{3}{50}\cdot\frac{2}{49}$.